# Plotting irregular raster object with tmap

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, rasterstack

I would like to use `tmap` R package to plot a RasterStack object. The problem is that the coordinates are not real coordinates, but rather climate variables, so I can not specify a valid reference coordinate system. I can plot this object in `ggplot` and `lattice`, but I would really like to do it in `tmap`.

```
> temp_object
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 400, 550, 220000, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.1, 10  (x, y)
extent     : -20, 35, 0, 4000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
names      :          X1 
min values : 0.001695915 
max values :   0.1038332 

> tm_shape(temp_object, bbox=tmaptools::bb(matrix(c(-20,0,35,4000),2,2))) + tm_raster()
Error: The projection of the shape object temp_shp is not known, while it seems to be projected.
```

If I try to specify a projection, I do get my plot, but the aspect of x and y is not OK and I did not find any argument in `tmap` R package, which could give me a desired aspect ratio.

```
crs(temp_object) <-  "+proj=lcc +lat_1=48 +lat_2=33 +lon_0=-100 +ellps=WGS84"
tm_shape(temp_object, bbox=tmaptools::bb(matrix(c(-20,0,35,4000),2,2))) + 
  tm_raster(legend.show = FALSE) + tm_grid()
```

[image]

Is there any argument in `tmap`, which would enable me to plot this raster with random aspect ratio? An example of such argument in `ggR` R package is argument `coord_equal = FALSE`.

```
  library(RStoolbox)
  ggR(temp_object,  coord_equal = F, geom_raster = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Can you share the data? If not, did you check the argument `asp` in `tm_layout`?

Comment: Hi, the asp argument does not change the aspect ratio in absolute terms. Sure, I can share the data, just let me know how . But if we can change the aspect ratio for examples relaying on built in or online data, then I can surely do it with my example. See simple example here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmap/vignettes/tmap-getstarted.html

Comment: Have you tried to change the resolution of your raster?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I can reproduce your problem and I don't know how to fix that, sorry. Maybe it's something related to the CRS of the input object (i.e. you should plot it according to some specific projection that allows different x and y ranges). If you don't receive any reply here maybe you can open a new issue in the tmap github repo.

Comment: The resolution would work, but only if I could transform only y axis. I don't think this is possible in r, or is it? the aggregate function from raster package will affect x and y in the same way.